# Formula for finding a Sum of Series, $\sum_{k=0}^{10} \frac{5}{k^4}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know that I can just add values (5 + 5/16 + 5/81 + ...), but is there any way of finding the value without having to chuck numbers into the calculator 10 times for each k ?

Thank you. :)

Edit: The reason I'm asking this is because I am trying to compute the upper and lower bounds for the following problem which I have worked on so far.

[Problem Part a.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crf66.jpg)

[Problem Part b, c, d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VTJm.jpg)

Comment: I suspect not...

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @JasSingh Hi, Jas! Thank you for expressing your concern! Things at MSE are a bit different than other sites, such as *Yahoo! Answers*—we are far more prestigious and have a system of up-voting, down-voting, and flagging. We use this system to enforce our expectations for all posts, which are outlined in [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). Part of this standard is that posts should be formatted clearly and in an effective or aesthetic manner. Though some people might click on those links, no one is going to sort through digitized chicken scratch. Please use MathJax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a good *approximation* if you notice that
$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1 {k^4}=H_n^{(4)}$$ where appear generalized harmonic numbers.

For large values of $n$,

$$H_n^{(4)}=\frac{\pi ^4}{90}-\frac{1}{3 n^3}+\frac{1}{2 n^4}-\frac{1}{3
   n^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$$ making $$S_{10}\approx \frac{\pi ^4}{90}-\frac{43}{150000}\approx \color{red}{1.0820365}67$$ while the exact value would be
$$S_{10}=\frac{43635917056897}{40327580160000}\approx 1.082036583$$